# Problem with row-wise operation in base R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, radix, rowwise

I have a problem with performing row-wise operations using 'apply' function in R. I want to calculate the distance between two points:

```
d <- function(x,y){
length <- norm(x-y,type="2")
as.numeric(length)
}
```

The coordinates are given by two dataframes:

```
start <- data.frame(
a = c(7, 5, 17, 1), 
b = c(5, 17, 1, 2))

stop <- data.frame( 
b = c(5, 17, 1, 2),
c = c(17, 1, 2, 1))
```

My point is to calculate successive distances given by start and stop coordiantes. I wish it worked like:

```
d(start[1,], stop[1,])
d(start[2,], stop[2,])
d(start[3,], stop[3,])
etc...
```

I have tried:

```
apply(X = start, MARGIN = 1, FUN = d, y = stop)
```

which brought some strange results. Can you please help me with finding the proper solution? I know how to perform the operation using dplyr rowwise() function, however my wish is to use base only.
Can you also explain me why did I receive such a strange results with apply()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the sequence of rows and apply the `d`

```
sapply(seq_len(nrow(start)), function(i) d(start[i,], stop[i,]))
[1] 12.165525 20.000000 16.031220  1.414214
```

---

Or if we want to use `apply`, create a single data by `cbind`ing the two data and then subset by indexing

```
apply(cbind(start, stop), 1, FUN = function(x) d(x[1:2], x[3:4]))
[1] 12.165525 20.000000 16.031220  1.414214
```

---

Or may use `dapply` for efficiency

```
library(collapse)
dapply(cbind(start, stop), MARGIN = 1, parallel = TRUE,
   FUN = function(x) d(x[1:2], x[3:4]))
[1] 12.165525 20.000000 16.031220  1.414214
```

Comment: Thank you! Which solution will be faster? The plan is to use it for ~300-10000 row data frames. Isn't the first solution the same fast as simple loop over the rows?

Comment: @Rafau  rowwise is generally slow.  if you want faster one, use `dapply` from `collapse` (updated)

Comment: @Rafau with `dapply` you can also use `parallel = TRUE` as well